# OracleDependency with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle11g

I want to use `OracleChangeNotifications` in an ASP.NET MVC 3 App. I have created a simple console application with the example code from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featChange.htm#ODPNT0025), and it works as expected. If I change the registered database table, a notification gets fired in the console application.

Then I created an ASP.NET MVC 3 app with the same sample code but the MVC app is not getting any notifications. Im using oracle 11g. Apparently the listener gets registered in the oracle database. If I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_change_notification_regs;
```

I get the following result:

```
REGID: 127

REGFLAGS: 4

CALLBACK: net8://(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=59747)?PR=0

OPERATIONS_FILTER: 0

CHANGELAG: 0

TIMEOUT: 48556

TABLE_NAME: MyTable
```

My guess is that IIS is somehow blocking the callback, but I cannot figure out why? 
Any ideas?

Heres is the code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using NLog;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace CacheTestWebApp.Services
{
    public class Notification
    {
        private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private const string ConnectionString = "<connection_string>";

        private const string TableName = "MyTable";

        private const string QueryString = "select * from " + TableName;

        public static void RegisterNotification()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var con = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    var cmd = new OracleCommand(QueryString, con);
                    var dependency = new OracleDependency();
                    dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;
                    dependency.AddCommandDependency(cmd);
                    cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
                    cmd.AddRowid = true;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Error(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void dependency_OnChange(object sender, OracleNotificationEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // handle notification
        }
    }
}
```

Notification.RegisterNotification() is executed in Application_Start() in the Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    Notification.RegisterNotification();
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using to access database with oracle .net provider?

Comment: Ok, now there is code :)